# php strtotime giving wrong results

Tags: php, date, strtotime

When I use the `strtotime` function it gives me different results on two different servers. 
One of them gives me the correct answer. It has php version 5.2.10.

On other server it gives me wrong date which has php version 5.0.4. 
I think that difference is the reason.

**Code:**

```
$fromDate = $_POST['fromDate']; // 25-11-2013
$strFromDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fromDate));
echo $strFromDate; // 2018-05-06
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: check timezones on servers.. If you want same result set timezones on both servers explicitly

Comment: It all depends on the default timezome set for that server. Do a `phpinfo()` on each and see what the difference is.

Comment: `Y-m-d` and you have `25-11-2013` <= `d-m-Y` something is NOT adding up.

Comment: Since PHP 5.0.4 is ancient and dead, I wouldn't be surprised if it's simply a bug. Seriously 5.0.4?! PS: Yup, looks like a bug/not yet supported format: http://3v4l.org/86gWq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably happens because PHP 5.0.4 doesn't yet support `d-m-Y` format, see **[here](http://3v4l.org/YMkCV)**.

Try to change format `d-m-Y` to `Y-m-d`. Here is one simple example:

```
$fromDate = '25-11-2013';
sscanf($fromDate, '%d-%d-%d', $d, $m, $Y);
$strFromDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$Y-$m-$d"));
echo $strFromDate;
```

**[This](http://3v4l.org/iv3ob)** will work on all PHP 4.x and 5.x versions

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is related to locales. Check if it is matching on both server.